# Incorrect syntax near '?'

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, ejs

I have 2 drop down menus that are being populated using a query in SQL Server. Based on the selected items, I am loading a different ejs template. I have done this using the help of AJAX. However, I want to be able to load the data according to the selected criteria. For instance, if `DD1` is selected as `Andrew` and `DD2` as `Date` the table should load 7 columns based on those conditions.

**AKA**

`SELECT * FROM exTable x WHERE x.Name = Andrew and x.Date = '4/22/2019`

**router.js**

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var name = await conn.query("SELECT DISTINCT pr.Name FROM WFS.PRTABLE pr WHERE pr.Functional_Group = 'Test'");
    var dates = await conn.query('SELECT r.Date FROM WFS.Dates r');
    res.render('index', {name : name , dates: dates});
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500)
        res.send(err.message)
      }
  });


router.post('/selection', async (req, res) =>{
  try {
    var name = await conn.query("SELECT DISTINCT pr.Name FROM WFS.PRTABLE pr WHERE pr.Group = 'Test'");
    var dates = await conn.query('SELECT r.Date FROM WFS.Dates r');

    var dateID = req.body.Dates;
    var nameID = req.body.Names;

    var tables = await conn.query("SELECT * FROM WFS.Views v WHERE v.Name = ? AND v.Date = ?", [ nameID , dateID ], function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
       res.render('selection', {tables: tables, name : name , dates: dates});
       });
    } 
      catch (err) {
        res.status(500)
        res.send(err.message)
    }
 });
```

**index.ejs**

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#date').on('change', function(event) {
                var dates = $('#selections option:selected').val();
            });
            $('#name').on('change', function(event) {
                var manVal = $('#selection option:selected').val();
                alert(manVal);
            });

            $('#submitData').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/selection",
                    data: {dates : dates , manVal: manVal},
                    success: function() {
                        alert('success');
                    }
                });
            });
        });    
    </script>
<form action="/selection" method="POST">
 <select class="DateDD" id="date" name="Dates">
      <% for(var n=0; n < dates.recordset.length; n++) { %>
           <option><%= dates.recordset[n].Date%></option>
      <% } %>
  </select>
  <select class="NameDD" id="name" name="Names">
      <% for(var n=0; n < name.recordset.length; n++) { %>
           <option><%= name.recordset[n].Name%></option>
      <% } %>
   </select>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submitData" class="btn btn-primary" value="View Report" />
</form>
```

**selection.ejs**

**CONTAINS THE SAME THING AS INDEX.EJS (besides the `<script>` tag) AND ...**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
    <% for(var n=0; n < tables.recordset.length; n++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=tables.recordset[n].Name%></td>
            <td><%=tables.recordset[n].Date%></td>
             ....
             ....
             ....
             ....
        </tr>
    <% } %>
    </table>
```

This is the error I receive: **Incorrect syntax near '?'** after I hit the submit button.

Comment: Not an express user, but your POST seems to be passing "dates" and "manVal" in the body, but you're trying to use "Dates" and "Names" as the query values for dateID and nameID in the controller's selection route.

Comment: That error message is coming from the database it's telling you that the "?" in "SELECT * FROM WFS.Views v WHERE v.Name = ? AND v.Date = ?" are not being replaced by the variables [ nameID , dateID ]...the database does not know what to do with WHERE v.Name = ?...

Comment: How would i be able to resolve this? @BillRuhl

Comment: I would try concatenating the string:  var myQuery = "SELECT * FROM WFS.Views v WHERE v.Name = '" + req.body.Names + "' AND v.Date = '" + req.body.Dates + "'";  Then you can pass it to your query function like: var tables = await conn.query(myQuery, function(err){...} I've never worked on a node project so I'm not going to post the answer, I just wanted to point out where the syntax error was coming from.

Comment: I have tried that.. I have also `console.log(req.body.Names)` and it gives me the value, but when i substitute it in the query it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Do console.log("SELECT * FROM WFS.Views v WHERE v.Name = '" + req.body.Names + "' AND v.Date = '" + req.body.Dates + "'") what is the output?

Comment: Says `Names` is not defined on the page.. However, it outputs the correct Name and date in the query

Comment: This is what I see when `console.log` it: **SELECT * FROM WFS.Views v WHERE v.Name = "Andrew" AND v.Date = 4/16/2019**

Comment: That query is not formatted correctly it needs to be formatted like this: SELECT * FROM WFS.Views v WHERE v.Name = 'Andrew' AND v.Date = '4/16/2019'      Name and date need to be surrounded be single quotes...as far as "Names is not defined on the page" that is a new error and you should post a new question for a Javascript dev to look at. I helped you with the sql server syntax....

Comment: Its wrapped in single quotes, sorry that was a typo... Thank you very much @BillRuhl